# How to hang IKEA KUNGSFOR kitchen suspension rails, partly in stud, partly in plasterboard

Tags: drywall, kitchens, fastening

I'm looking to install 2 [IKEA KUNGSFOR suspension rails](https://www.ikea.com/gb/en/p/kungsfors-suspension-rail-stainless-steel-80334858/) to create a combination close to [this](https://www.ikea.com/gb/en/p/kungsfors-suspension-rail-with-shelf-wll-grid-stainless-steel-s19254332/), but with 1 fewer shelf and using a [grid](https://www.ikea.com/gb/en/p/kungsfors-wall-grid-stainless-steel-80334919/) on the back instead.

My kitchen is fairly small (formed from the recesses of 2 other rooms) and the wall I want to mount the rails / grid / shelf on is a stud partition wall.

I am able to line up one of the suspension rails with a stud, but not the other.

For the stud fastenings I planned on using 3 x 5ø 60mm wood screws.

For the plasterboard fastenings I'm not sure what the best option is. The weight of the setup before any load is:

- 2 x Suspension Rails: 1.0kg each = 2.0kg
- Grid: 1.3kg
- Shelf: 2.5kg
- Magnetic Rail: 0.7kg
- **Total: 6.5kg**

Ultimately this will be used for storing knives (on the magnetic rail), various kitchen implements (e.g. spoons, spatulas, ladle etc.) and on the shelf a stainless steel pot and pan. It won't be used for extraordinarily heavy loads (e.g. cast iron pans, heavy jars, etc.)

**What would be the most suitable fixing for the 1 rail that needs to be fastened to plasterboard, if safely possible?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know you say you are not going to put a row of heavy jars on - but you are probably going to leave that in place when you eventually move out, and the new owner may have different ideas.

For this sort of application I would go for the strongest fixings available - which are a gravity toggle.  Fischer claim theirs have a pull-out strength of 20kg which gives you plenty of margin for error.

[This page](http://www.fischer.in.th/PortalData/31/Resources/sales_documents/product_range_literature/pdfs/Plasterboard_Fixings_Guide_webversion.pdf) gives details of the various sorts of plasterboard fixing available, and their ratings. (Note: that is the Fischer site, but other manufacturers have very similar products available.)

Comment: Thanks for this - do ‘gravity toggles’ go by other names? Looking on Screwfix.co.uk and can only see 1 thing that’s a close match.

Comment: @codinghands Looks like not.  Incidentally, I would start with toolstation and only go to screwfix if necessary.  https://www.toolstation.com/screws-fixings/cavity-fixings/c100  doesn't have gravity toggles either, but it does have the "metal cavity fixing" which is almost as good.  (The gripit fixing there appear to be overkill to me.)

Comment: I’ve struggled with the inconsistent / brand-specific naming of things so keen to make sure I’m on the right track :) something like https://www.toolstation.com/fischer-hm-s-metal-cavity-fixing/p40084?

Comment: @codinghands Yes.